# Python release memory when changing member of a object within the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have been playing around with Python objects in IDLE and observed that if a member variable of an object is changed, the memory isn't released! Here is an example:

```
import weakref
import gc

class subclass():
    def __init__(self, data):
         self.data=data
    def __repr__(self):
    return self.data.__str__()

class newclass():
    def __init__(self,data):
         self.data=subclass(data)
    def test(self):
         refs=weakref.ref(self.data)()
         self.data=None
         gc.collect()
         print ("ref", refs)

a = newclass(data=3)
a.test()
print ("val", a.data)
```

The output of this code, I would expect to be:

```
ref None
val None
```

It turns out that the ref, however, is still a valid reference and the output is:

```
ref 3
val None
```

I would like to see that memory being released. I would like to understand how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood something crucial, unfortunately. When you call the `weakref` object returned from `weakref.ref` *you get back the original object*. Try printing `type(ref)` and see how `<class '__main__.subclass'>` is returned. See the [docs on `weakref.ref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref):

> The *original object can be retrieved by **calling** the reference object* if the referent is still alive; if the referent is no longer alive, calling the reference object will cause `None` to be returned.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

You called the reference object and got your class `subclass` back; a reference to it therefore still exists in `ref` not allowing it to get garbage-collected.

*If you don't call it*, on the other hand, you'll notice how the line `print('ref', refs)` indicates that the reference is dead:

```
ref <weakref at 0x7f3028188a48; dead>
val None
```

i.e as the sole reference to your object and due to the fact it is weak, it got collected.

As an aside, if you want to be portable between Python 2 and 3 you'll want your classes to subclass from `object` and not use empty parentheses `()`. If you don't care about portability, the parentheses can be dropped without change in semantics. :-)

Comment: In python 3 subclassing from object is implicit, but I think it is a good stylistic point and it helps make your code easily portable to Python 2. And, as we all know, explicit is better than implicit :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree (even though that was actually edited in by 2ps :-)

Comment: Thanks. Got it now!